# Java String to Collection Type

Tags: java, api, collections

In my application there is requirement to convert huge data to CSV and to read CSV. Where I am facing an issue to convert `Strings to Collection Type`. For example, I am having a line in CSV file as follows,

```
1,{'Id_101', 'Id_102', 'Id_103'}
```

In my code, I will be reading the above line with `String[]` variable So,

```
arr[0] will hold 1
arr[1] will hold {'Id_101', 'Id_102', 'Id_103'}
```

I know the data type of `arr[1] value is Set (It is static)`. I need to convert the `{'Id_101', 'Id_102', 'Id_103'}  to Set<String>`.

Similarly `for Map too`, the input will be like `{ "keyA": "ValA", "keyB": "ValB" }` (I know the when the String is of type Set and when the string is of Map, since it is static)

Is there is any third party API available for that? I don't like to use String manipulations. Need to achieve with any third party API's..

Comment: why don't you use json and write every object as separate line in the file?

Comment: Conversion to CSV is another third party tool, So I cant do any changes in the writing process of CSV

Comment: while reading use  csvToJSON, then using JSON (like GSON) API you can convert to deserved types easily

Answer (score 0):

```
String temp = arr[1];
//remove the leading and trailing brackets
temp = temp.substring(1, temp.length()-1);
String arr[] = temp.split(", ");

//convert array of String to Set
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Comment: Any solution apart from String Manipulations?

Comment: what do you mean apart from String manipulations? what kind of other solutions you are looking for?

Comment: without using substring and charAt etc.. In some cases the string may contains ,space with the value itself

Comment: then you have to write the logic according to your needs. You can also use starting `'` and ending `'` to differentiate the values. I can only answer according to the info you provided.

Comment: @JayaAnanthram what about using the split technique with the single-quote as separator, then taking from the array the values at odd indices? I think no string manipulation would be needed